# Perf Backtrace not Reproducible in Pin

Tags: linux, gdb, callstack, perf, intel-pin

I ran `Perf` multiple times and there were many backtraces in all of them not reproducible in `Pin`. Note that `GDB` could reproduce those backtraces. Here, I will show one of them:

```
evince 13293  3713.930210:        100 mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp:     7ffff5733440         5080022 N/A|SNP N/A|TLB N/A|LCK N/A
    7ffff54b0226 g_private_get_impl+0x6 (inlined)
    7ffff54b0226 g_private_get+0x6 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff5487f23 thread_memory_from_self+0x93 (inlined)
    7ffff5487f23 g_slice_free1+0x93 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff5466c72 g_source_callback_unref+0x22 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff54676eb g_source_destroy_internal+0x6b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff546a30f g_main_dispatch+0x1df (inlined)
    7ffff546a30f g_main_context_dispatch+0x1df (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff546a64f g_main_context_iterate+0x1ff (inlined)
    7ffff546a6db g_main_context_iteration+0x2b (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    7ffff5a2be3c g_application_run+0x1fc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
    555555573707 main+0x447 (/opt/evince-3.28.4/bin/evince)
    7ffff4a91b96 __libc_start_main+0xe6 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so)
    555555573899 _start+0x29 (/opt/evince-3.28.4/bin/evince)
```

The backtrace says that `g_source_callback_unref()` should call `g_slice_free1()` at the first point before offset `0x22`. But under `Pin`, the immediate sequential execution of the call point and callee entry point does not happen, at all. Here is the call point disassembly (look at offset `33`):

```
Dump of assembler code for function g_source_callback_unref:
   0x0000000000048c50 <+0>: lock subl $0x1,(%rdi)
   0x0000000000048c54 <+4>: je     0x48c60 <g_source_callback_unref+16>
   0x0000000000048c56 <+6>: repz retq 
   0x0000000000048c58 <+8>: nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000048c60 <+16>: push   %rbx
   0x0000000000048c61 <+17>: mov    0x18(%rdi),%rax
   0x0000000000048c65 <+21>: mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x0000000000048c68 <+24>: test   %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000048c6b <+27>: je     0x48c73 <g_source_callback_unref+35>
   0x0000000000048c6d <+29>: mov    0x10(%rdi),%rdi
   0x0000000000048c71 <+33>: callq  *%rax
   0x0000000000048c73 <+35>: mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x0000000000048c76 <+38>: pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000048c77 <+39>: jmpq   0x51ba0 <g_free>
End of assembler dump.
```

In fact in all problematic cases that I checked, the calls were indirect. What is wrong with the `Pin` execution?

**UPDATE:**

In `Pin`, I used two analyses both of which failed to find the sequence:

Suppose that `IP1` and `IP2` are the caller (the `callq` instruction above) and the called (the start address of `g_slice_free1()`) instruction pointers.

**1) (High overhead)** A simple analysis routine that checks every single instruction and records the **last** and **second-to-last** instruction until these match `IP1` and `IP2`.

**2) (Low overhead)** An analysis routine that checks the target of the `callq` instruction at `IP1` and notifies if it matches `IP2`. The instrumentation part is something like this:

```
...
if (INS_Address(ins) == IP1)
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)targetFinder, IARG_BRANCH_TARGET_ADDR, IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_END)
...
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I did the high overhead analysis in `DynamoRIO` and faced exactly the same problem. In other words, `g_slice_free1()` is **never** called in the benchmark based on the analyses in both `Pin` and `DynamoRIO`. Therefore, it seems reasonable to doubt `Perf` output. Is it possible for `Perf` to report a backtrace that has never occured during program execution?

**UPDATE 3:**

It seems that in most of the cases the problem is with `Perf`. Most of the backtraces are corrupted with repeated function calls. For example, here is one of them with two `gmallocn()`s:

```
EvJobScheduler 10021  8653.926478:        100 mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:uppp:     7fffd1062a00         5080022 N/A|SNP N/A|TLB N/A|LCK N/A
   7ffff4b07207 tcache_get+0x197 (inlined)
   7ffff4b07207 __GI___libc_malloc+0x197 (inlined)
   7fffd9872fb9 gmalloc+0x59 (inlined)
   7fffd9872fb9 gmallocn+0x59 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffd9872fb9 gmallocn+0x59 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffd9951e6f _ZN8TextLine8coalesceEP10UnicodeMap+0xff (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffd9952f82 _ZN9TextBlock8coalesceEP10UnicodeMapd+0x752 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffd995bc37 _ZN8TextPage8coalesceEbdb+0x1507 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffd995cb71 _ZN13TextOutputDev7endPageEv+0x31 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.73.0.0)
   7fffe803c6d2 _ZL26poppler_page_get_text_pageP12_PopplerPage+0x92 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-glib.so.8.9.0)
   7fffe803deb3 poppler_page_get_selection_region+0x63 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-glib.so.8.9.0)
   7fffe82ab650 [unknown] (/opt/evince-3.28.4/lib/evince/4/backends/libpdfdocument.so)
   7ffff795f165 ev_job_page_data_run+0x2f5 (/opt/evince-3.28.4/lib/libevview3.so.3.0.0)
   7ffff7961309 ev_job_thread+0xe9 (inlined)
   7ffff7961309 ev_job_thread_proxy+0xe9 (/opt/evince-3.28.4/lib/libevview3.so.3.0.0)
   7ffff5492194 g_thread_proxy+0x54 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.4)
   7ffff4e686da start_thread+0xda (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so)
   7ffff4b9188e __GI___clone+0x3e (inlined)
```

While offset `0x59` (i.e., `89` in decimal) does not show any recursion. It is justified below:

```
...
0x00000000000b2fb0 <+80>:   je     0xb2fd0 <gmallocn(int, int)+112>
0x00000000000b2fb2 <+82>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
0x00000000000b2fb5 <+85>:   callq  0xae880 <malloc@plt>
0x00000000000b2fba <+90>:   test   %rax,%rax
0x00000000000b2fbd <+93>:   je     0xb2fd8 <gmallocn(int, int)+120>
...
```

It is a simple call to `malloc()`.

I'm totally confused. Please share your opinions.
Regards.

Comment: TheAhmad, Hello, could you please check is offset 33 is decimal or hex offset? 0x48c50+0x22 = 0x48c72; 33 decimal is 0x21. Could you please also point where are Pin results in your question?

Comment: @osgx: Those `<+29>` / `<+33>` offsets from the function-start in GDB-style dumps are decimal offsets.  `mov  0x10(%rdi),%rdi` is a 4-byte instruction, not 10.

Comment: Pin can need with the app memory layout, are ip1 and ip2 absolute addresses or relative ones?

Comment: They are absolute addresses. OK. At least, now, I know that it seems also strange to you. Perhaps I did something wrong.